# openGL texture loading -> weird looking result [mac, glfw, stb_image]

Tags: macos, opengl, textures, glfw

i am having trouble loading textures in opengl.

i am writing cpp on a mac and have a hard time. i don't understand why i am having these ugly textures. i am using stb_image.c to load the textures, but it doesnt seem to work correctly.

here is my code:

```
unsigned int TextureHelper::loadTexture(std::string pathToTexture){ 
std::cout << "Loading " << pathToTexture << std::endl;
unsigned int img;
glGenTextures(1,&img);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,img);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

/* Load Texture with stb_image */
int width, height, n;
unsigned char * data = stbi_load(pathToTexture.c_str(), &width, &height, &n, 4);
if(!data){
    printf("Error, while loading texture: %s\n", stbi_failure_reason());
}else{
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    stbi_image_free(data);
    std::cout << "returning " << pathToTexture << " = "  << img << "x" << width << "x" << height << "x" << n << std::endl;
    return img;
}
std::cout << "returning " << pathToTexture << " = "  << 0 << std::endl;
return 0;
```

}

i have tried GL_RGBA, GL_RGBA8, GL_RGB, GL_RGBA..but nothing seems to work. am i missing something?

as for the gl context, i am using GLFW and the apple gl3.h

format of the tex is .png

here come the textures :)

[(texture - how it looks)](http://www.deadkitteninaframe.com/files/stack/pic.jpg)

[(texture - how it SHOULD look)](http://www.deadkitteninaframe.com/files/stack/cube_uv.png)

**UPDATE: SOLVED**
alright guys. i have solved it. sorry for posting ;)
it is a "bit" embarrassing^^... the code up there works fine. my problem was, that i forgot to set up the glfw colorbits and depth...

adding this

```
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RED_BITS, 8);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_GREEN_BITS, 8);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_BLUE_BITS, 8);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_ALPHA_BITS, 8);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DEPTH_BITS, 32);
```

before my window creation solved the problem.